# Чем обосновано тире.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

В данном случае О безударная, значит загораем, а когда падает ударение - ставят А.

Чем обосновано тире в данном предложении?Авторским замыслом? Не могу понять...

Возможно ли такое написание этого предложения :

В данном случае(двоеточие?)О безударная - загораем,падает ударение - ставим А.

Comment: Не очень понятно.Во-первых, второе предложение имеет союз КОГДА, это не БСП. Во-вторых, первое предложение бессоюзное, хорошо бы тире поставить. В-третьих, слово "значит" не обособлено - какова его грамматическая роль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"В данном случае О безударная, значит загораем, а когда падает ударение - ставят А". Этот вариант лучше, правильнее. А тире в части "падает ударение - ставим А" объясняется известным правилом о том, что в бессоюзном сложном предложении тире ставится,если первая часть сложного предложения обозначает время или условие того, о чем говорится во второй части предложения (если (когда) падает ударение, то ставят А.)

Comment: Это интересно.Спасибо.